# Predictive text option does not exist on my iPhone 6

Tags: ios, keyboard

The option for `Predictive` text has never existed in the settings of my iPhone, as shown in many different forums. When I navigate `Settings`->`General`->`Keyboards` to see all the options, after `Enable Caps Lock` there goes `Smart Punctuation`.

I tried typing text and pushing longer on the "globe" icon but all I get are my installed keyboards of different languages and options to make it a one-hand keyboard.

How can I enable `Predictive` text?

I have an `iPhone 6`, with `iOS 11.1`.

Comment: Which language keyboards do you have active?

Comment: "Swedish", "Emoji" and "Lithuanian". I tried searching through "Add New Keyboard" but found only either other languages or Bitmoji.

Comment: Predictive text is not provided for any of those.  Check the tech specs for a list.

Comment: If you add English to your keyboard list, do you then have a predictive text option for that keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add English to your keyboard list.

Comment: After adding English, a tab called "English" appeared, where I can turn on/off predictive text. So as I understand, I cannot get predictive text for Swedish because the dictionary of it doesn't exist on iOS.

Comment: @skooog  There is a Swedish spellcheck dictionary and reference dictionary on iOS.  But predictive text is only available for the languages listed in the tech specs, and Swedish is not yet among them.